# Is a association of general solution and odd solution consider a soultion to an ordinary differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

(1) For example we have

$ y^2+(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x})^2=1
$,

then the general solutions are

$y=\cos(C-x)$,

and the special solutions (odd solutions) are

$y=\pm1$.

Is this a solution for the differential equation?

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}
y=1 , & x\le 0\\
 y=\cos (x) ,& x>0
\end{matrix}\right.
$

(2) A further question will be, as my understanding a solution of a first order differential equation can be seen as a curve follow the direction field. Combined with the previous example, a point moves along with the direction field when it move into the position has two solutions, it can choose either direction?

Comment: Yes and yes, see for instance the Clairaut equations where this happens regularly. In the given example, you can stop and stay at the north- and south pole as often and as long as you want.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann Thanks!!